# SQL Server error 'Can't Find Procedure'... after I have moved the DB

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio solution with a database project which I spit out to SSMS whenever I hit Publish.

Recently I noticed that the default Data File Location, for the DB and log files, is the server's `C:\` drive. Obviously it's bad practice for to store a huge database, with it's files on the `C:\` drive. So I want the files at some point during the Publish moved to another drive.

This is what I am trying to do:

- I hit Publish, which creates the DB and puts the DB & log files onto `C:\`, as usual (1)
- at this point, no data has been ingested, so the DB is just an empty shell with SPs, functions, etc (2)
- I then execute the code block below which puts the DB & log files onto my `Y:\` drive (3)
- I then execute the rest of my Post Deployment script (4)

However, the script now only gets as far completing (3). As soon as it starts (4), it hits a line which calls a procedure and then fails with

> Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.usp_mySP'

If I don't run the below code, and thus not move the DB files, the whole project runs smoothly.

```
-- SOME CODE HERE... WORKS FINE...    

-- set DB offline
    ALTER DATABASE [dbName] SET OFFLINE

    -- physically move the DB's primary file and lof file (using the command line)
    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(512)
    SET @cmd = 'move "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\dbName_Primary.mdf" "Y:\SQLData"'
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
    SET @cmd = 'move "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\dbName_Primary.ldf" "Y:\SQLData"'
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd

    -- logically move the files using T-SQL
    ALTER DATABASE [dbName] MODIFY FILE
    (
        NAME = [dbName]
        ,FILENAME = 'Y:\SQLData\dbName_Primary.mdf'
    )
    ALTER DATABASE [dbName] MODIFY FILE
    (
        NAME = [dbName_log]
        ,FILENAME = 'Y:\SQLData\dbName_Primary.ldf'
    )

    -- set DB online
    ALTER DATABASE [dbName] SET ONLINE


-- REST OF SCRIPT HERE, INCLUDING CALL TO [dbo].[usp_mySP]... CRASHES
```

Comment: Just for anyone else's reference: the solution has been supplied as found below on the accepted answer, and is to add the line `USE [dbName]` straight after the code that moves all the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting a GO statement after altering the database to online.

**Edit**

Since that didn't do it I begin to wonder if you're executing the statements on the correct database. You might need to explicitly name the database as [database].[schema].[spname], or insert a `GO` statement and a `use database` statement right after.

Comment: I'm afraid that adding a GO after the 'altering the database to online' statement (or any of the other statements in that block) hasn't fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of code calling a stored procedure? You might be trying to execute it on the master database.

Comment: I edited my answer with more suggestions. That's as far as I can go without more information.

Comment: Hi John, sorry for the delay. In asnwer to your question 'Can you provide a sample of code calling a stored procedure?'... `EXEC [imp].[usp_LoadImportInformation] @FilePath = @DataFilePath, @DirListFile = @DirListFile`

Comment: Ok then try as my edit suggests. You seem to be executing that script on a different database..

Comment: Glad I could help :-)